# Do we always have to treat states as immutable in Reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

I'm a beginner in React & Redux and I am confused with manipulating the state in Reducers.
In most of the articles, documentations, I keep seeing that the states are immutable and we should never update the state.  We should always use `...state` or `object.assign` in the reducers

However, in famous tutorials ([Cory House](https://zombiecodekill.com/2016/05/27/react-and-redux-async-status-and-error-handling/) or other places (Eg. [Here on GitHub](https://github.com/hitesh00025/React-Redux-ES6-Sample-App/blob/master/src/reducers/ajaxStatusReducer.js)) , they update the state the directly like the following:

```
var initialState = {
    numberOfAjaxCall: 0
}

const ajaxStatusReducer = (state = initialState.numberOfAjaxCall, action) => {
        if (action.type === AJAX_BEGIN_CALL) {
            return state + 1;
        }

        return state;
}
```

Why these codes are not written like the following?

```
var initialState = {
        numberOfAjaxCall: 0
    }

const ajaxStatusReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    if (action.type === AJAX_BEGIN_CALL) {
    return {
        ...state, 
        numberOfAjaxCall: state.numberOfAjaxCall + 1
        };
    }

return state;
}
```

I would like to know whether my code is wrong or not.  Or I misunderstood about Redux & Reducers or don't understand the way these codes are implemented?

Could you please help me to enlighten about these coding styles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example doesn't mutate state - it returns a new number. In that case the reducer is responsible for only the one number.

If your state is shaped like in the example you gave:

```
var initialState = {
    numberOfAjaxCall: 0
}
```

The reducer `ajaxStatusReducer` is responsible for `numberOfAjaxCall` only. You will still need another reducer for the overall state object, which could look something like this (simplest option, lots of other ways you could write this):

```
function reducer(state, action) {
    return {
        numberOfAjaxCall: ajaxStatusReducer(state.numberOfAjaxCall, action)
    };
}
```

In the second example, you combine both of these reducers into one. Both are valid options and it depends on how you like to compose your code/reducers in general.